# Deep Search in the android file system for text files

Tags: android, search, filesystems, sys

I would like to search within the Android file system for finding text files containing specific information (e.g., the device's battery current and voltage).

I tried to use the Astro File Browser but it seems that its search functionality does not support deep search (search within children directories as well).

I also tried to copy the directory in which I would like to search (the /sys/ directory) to my PC's hard drive using ADB but unfortunately this doesn't work as most of the files aren't copied due to missing reading access.

Do you no any working solution to browse the file system (either from a PC or via an Android app)?

Comment: did you look at eclipse->ddms->device->file explorer ?

Comment: Astro found it fine for me, /sys/class/battery/..

Comment: Well yes, of course I found /sys/class/battery/ however, for the Asus TF101 there is no current information within this directory, only voltage. Thus, I wanted to check whether or not it is somewhere else in the file system without looking into every directory manually ;)

Comment: You could try "aGrep":<br/>
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.aGrep
<br/><br/>
or "DroidGrep":<br/>
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidgrep

Answer (score 1):

Each manufacturer puts files in different places (or at least can). Try using the API to access this information:

There is an intent, [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)

And the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) class

As for browsing the file system, Astro works fine - but if the OS is not granting you permissions, you will not be able to read it unless you root your phone.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Unfortunately, the API does not provide the current (ameprage) information, only voltage is available. However, for power consumption I need the current as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? It may help if your question was more clear - as now it really only asks how to search your Android's file system.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I want to write a little profiling application that allows to profile the energy consumption of the Android device in Watt. Thus, I need consumption values for both voltage and current. Howver, the Android API itself only supports access to the battery's voltage.

Comment: Do you have this file? It seemed to solve this problem for others. /sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I guess, its a bad sign?

Comment: I don't either, only place I've seen which contains the current/draw

Answer (score 1):

I now implemented a simple, stupid Java method that can be executed from the Eclipse ADT to search in the file system and it works (however, slowly):

```
public static List<File> getFilesOfDirectory(File dir, String fileNamePart) {

    List<File> result;

    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()
            && !dir.getAbsolutePath().contains("root")
            && dir.getAbsolutePath().split("/").length < 10) {
        Log.i("fileSearch", "search in directory " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files != null)
            result = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(files));
        else
            result = new ArrayList<File>();
    }

    else
        result = Collections.emptyList();

    /* Filter for interesting files. */
    List<File> filteredResult = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : result) {
        if (file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase()
                .contains(fileNamePart.toLowerCase()))
            filteredResult.add(file);
        // no else.
    }

    /* Search recursively. */
    List<File> furtherResults = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : result) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
            furtherResults.addAll(getFilesOfDirectory(file, fileNamePart));
        // no else.
    }
    // end for.

    filteredResult.addAll(furtherResults);

    return filteredResult;
}
```

The method can be called using a file object representing the root directory to be searched (e.g., new File("/")) and a String representing file names to be found (e.g., "voltage").

Comment: Better of using a `FileNameFilter`...This code is prone to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Oops. I did not no FileNameFilters, yet. Thanks for the remark.